# Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, web-config, web-deployment

After searching my question's answer from stack overflow and other forums i am going to ask it myself,  may be some one can guide me and make my way easy with asp.net programming.

I have a issue with saving values from my live website to database but all time i got error.

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

i have tried to view  it by putting mode=off in my web.config but i am unable to view details of my error.

here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
      <authentication mode="None"/>
    </system.web>
  <location allowOverride="true">
    <appSettings>

      <add key="#" value="Password=#;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=#;Initial Catalog=#;Data Source=#"/>

    </appSettings>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I have tested my database and my connection string on my live database using local solution of my project but when ever i tried to test it using my live server which is arvixe i am unable.

My fellow suggest me to use

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="#" connectionString="Data Source=#;Initial Catalog=#;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
  </connectionStrings>
```

but it is not working with live server.
I am using app settings for connection string and i am confident with it because it is working fine with my local and live database.

I request to developers to test my [online quran reading](http://www.onlinequranreading.org/ContactUs.aspx) page and try to figure it out.

Comment: I don't think this will help you, but remove the <compilation debug="true"/> in production web site. What database version are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: @gmailuser i will try tonight with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Sql Express, try this connection string

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=DBName;User ID=abcd;Password=xxxx;`

As far as I know `Integrated Security=True` works with `windows authentication`. If you want to use this option then change the `<authentication mode="None"/>` to `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`.

If you are using Sql Server, may be try the following connection string

**Standard Connection string**

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

**Trusted Connection**

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`

Comment: If you see my question i have set <authentication mode="None"/>

Comment: Read Properly. I want to say change it to  <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Comment: You have a type in your answer, Wondows => Windows